# delete cells but not rows

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have an excel sheet where I am pulling data from other worksheets into separate columns per worksheet I pull from. I am trying to find any duplicates in any of my columns and delete all the duplicates (for example: if there are three of the code 12gb, I want to be left with one 12gb). I want this so that I can count how many unique values there are (automatically) and then populate a graph automatically. I have tried many different formulas to do this but I am thinking a VBA code is needed, however I have never used that coding before so I am not sure what to do.Below is an example of three columns of my excel sheet:(I wasn't able to post images/excel sheets)

```
12gb        sdf     vfg
22rg        tttyhg  dsf
dfg455      ggff    df
fgfg        fff     vcs
4redd       ccv     dfgh
56ff        66hg    66y
yygf        66y     56ff
66ygt       yggfg   12gb
ghhg        
            vfg
```

Comment: If this is a one time thing... Manually make the 3 columns 1.  Then use data remove duplicates.  then put 1 column back into 3.  If you need to do this multiple times, record a macro. doing this.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hackish macro it relies on specific columns and placements so I'm not a big fan of this solution.

It was generated by recording the manual tasks I did

- adding a row to denote end of columns
- copying the columns 2 and 3 to the end of column 1.
- removing the duplicates in column a
- then manually creating the 3 columns again. based on the end of column notes added.

.

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("A12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1----"
Range("B12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2----"
Range("C12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3----"
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Cut
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A13").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B13").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("A13").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A25").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$46").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
Range("A13:A22").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A23").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Cut
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B13").Select
```

Now this assumes Row data isn't relevant.  If it is... this will not work. as Excel deletes the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, although i'm sure there are more elegant ways. in principle i just put each value into an array after checking if the value is not already in the array:

```
Sub del_values()
Dim last_row, last_col, size, y As Integer
Dim arr() As Variant

'finding the last row and last column and calculating the possible size of the array

last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
last_col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
size = last_row * last_col
y = 0

'adjusting the array-size    
ReDim arr(size)

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, last_col))

'avoiding blank cells
If cell.Value > "" Then

'checking if value is already in the array - if not, add it to the array and increase y - if it is, clear the contents of the cell
If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, arr, 0)) Then
arr(y) = cell.Value
y = y + 1
Else
Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).ClearContents
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

i was not sure what you wanted to do with the cells containing duplicates, so i just cleared the contents - you could of course just delete them with

```
Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).delete
```

by the way, y is equal to the number of unique values, if you want to use it directly.